# datagrip - collect query results that runs repeatedly on a set time interval

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I have a query.

```
select count(*), now() from some_table;
```

which prints out a result that looks like this:

```
{some_number}   {timestamp}
```

Now on DataGrip there's a clock button which allows you to keep running this query on a set interval:

[image]

So every 60 seconds, or every two minutes or whathaveyou. However, it keeps *updating* the results, whereas what I want to happen is *collect* them in one result page until it'll look something like this:

```
{some_number}   2023-02-15 12:15:56.882545 +00:00
{some_number}   2023-02-15 12:16:56.882545 +00:00
{some_number}   2023-02-15 12:17:56.882545 +00:00
```

i.e. I want to see changes over time. I can develop something on the backend that will do it, but it's just a quick test I need to run on a certain table to try and identify an issue, and it really feels like there's some way of doing it in datagrip. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This feature was meant to update the result set periodically, but not to collect or accumulate data of a certain database object. To achieve your goal, you can use a raise statement to collect data over a period of time.